# Template Path Hints not showing on front-end in magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8

I followed the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19062365/4684797) but no template hints are appearing. 
I even switched the browser and deactivated caching in Magento.

However, nothing appears.

I am working for a company which works with an agency, maybe they have removed the code for the template hint generation for whatever reason.

Please help me to find out what is going on.

Comment: Please check the same configuration by changing the configuration scope if you have multiple stores, store views. Also check if there is any IP added on the first tab.

Comment: Good hint, but I already checked the configuration scope, it is set to the correct store.

Comment: ok did you check the IP tab?

Comment: Do you mean "Developer Client restriction"? There is an IP, but I think it has nothing to do with it and I think it is needed so only my company can see the site?

Comment: No you just add your IP there and save the config.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, you are right! It works after removing the IP! Thanks! Please write an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77579/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-black).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Developer Client restriction under System -> Configuration -> Developer for particular store. Either you can add your IP with comma separated or remove the existing ones.

Hope this helps!